# Weka and CSV files

Tags: csv, weka

I'm currently trying to import some data into weka. Currently the data is in a CSV file, and consists of a numerical ID and then some string data(Tweets). I'm getting an error where it is reading "Wrong number of values, Read 1, expected 2 Token[EOL], line 17". I'm using quotes as my enclosure characters for the String data. I understand that something(presumably an EOL character?) is causing weka to incorrectly separate some of the String data into multiple entries on the same line, but I'm not sure how to fix the EOL token problem.

My data set can be viewed here. The current data set is on Sheet 2:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yclu0t4ITFWn6itYBsVtkGalmP9BPaWFFP6U6jAeLMU/edit?usp=sharing

The text file itself may be found here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B433FqC3TscQQkRxZklQclA3Z3M/view?usp=sharing

Current error is now on the 3rd line, with the same error. The only newline character there is the one at the end of the line denoting a new entry, so I'm not sure why its having issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its datasets, Weka considers a `newline` character as an indication of the end of instance. Your line 17 is actually a multi-line tweet which confuses Weka. You can use either

1. a RegEx to get rid of the `newline` characters in every single tweet or
2. during downloading the tweets, clean the tweets to get rid of any `newline` character in them.

Unfortunately, Weka does not have a mechanism to get rid of this problem by itself (as far as I know).

---

### **EDIT**

Okay, here are some other things that need to be fixed (according to your EDITS in the question):

1. Replace `'` with `\'`
2. Replace `grave accent` with `\grave accent`
3. Many tweets contain quotes inside quotes. The inside double quotes (`"`) should be replaced by `\"`
4. If you put your tweets inside double quotes, then your header should be `id, "text"`
5. Some tweets contain two consecutive double quotes, get rid of them or replace them with `\"`.
6. I cannot say exactly where, because I lost trace, but I think still some tweets contain new lines in them (or at least one tweet has it still)

These are just a few things that I noticed. There might be more. Time will tell.

Comment: So I went through my CSV file and got rid of all of the newline characters which are in there due to multi-line tweets. I replaced them just with blank spaces instead, although I'm now getting the same error on the new line 3. I'm unsure why weka is having a problem with this, as the only newline character here as at the end of the line, which should denote the next entry. I've updated the post with the fixed csv file.

Comment: Did you upload this "cleaned" dataset? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Yeah, I just added it to the post.

Comment: I used this answer's information to create a python package that fetches tweets and lets you sanitize the tweet text to be 'weka-friendly' Thanks so much!

Here's a link to it
https://github.com/pacu/phron